# React+Sass+Webpack local styling issue

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, webpack, css-loader

I'm using a using a [3rd party react component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input), and I'm having trouble configuring my sass correctly.  This component creates a series of `<li>` html tags, and if one of the `<li>` has been clicked on it adds gives that item an "active" class name: `<li class="active">`.  I would like to customize the css for that **active** `<li>` element. To do this, I created a Test.scss file containing the following:

```
.tag_input li.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

To use this styling, I do the following react

```
import classes from './Test.scss'
export const Test = (props) => {
  return (
    <ReactTags
        classNames={{
            tags: classes.tag_input,
        }}
     ... 
    >
  )
}
```

The problem is that when Webpack loads this Sass file, it uses [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader), which converts each classname in each local .sass file to the following format: "localIdentName=[name]_[local]__[hash:base64:5]".  That means my css no longer applies to a `<li class="active">`.  Instead it now works for `<li classname="Test__active___2LBGS">`.  I've thought of two (bad) solutions so far:

1. I somehow reconfigure webpack to not rename certain css class names using the localIdentName
2. I somehow get `<ReactTags />` to use the classname: Test__active___2LBGS

Neither of these seem feasible so I'm pretty stuck!! Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [css-loader documentation](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) under **Local scope** you can apply :global to styles, that you don't want the loader to convert:

```
:global (.tag_input li.active) {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the className prop and to set an active state you would update the props

```
<ReactTags className={props.active ? classes.tagInputActive : classes.tagInput}/>
```